# how to pass values from callback function from service to controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-controller

How can I access values returned from service using controller. In my code  service.js function **showInfo()** returns JSON objects. But I cannot access these objects outside this function. If I try to do console.log from controller.js

**console.log(chartService.showInfo.new_data)**

I get

***error Cannot read property 'new_data' of undefined*.**

Same happens if I try to

**console.log(chartService.showInfo)**

I get ***undefined*.**

How can I access the JSON object new_data inside function showInfo from the controller?

**Service.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .service('chartService', function (){
  return {
     getUrl: function init(path) {
        Tabletop.init( { key: path,
                         callback: showInfo,
                         simpleSheet: true } )
     }
  }

     function showInfo(data, tabletop){

          var new_data = JSON.stringify(data.map(function(el) {
            return {
                "name": el[Object.keys(el)[0]],
                "y": +el[Object.keys(el)[1]]
            };
     }));
   }
})
```

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')    
      .controller('piechartCtrl', [ '$scope', 'chartService',  function (chartService, $scope) {
        console.log(chartService.showInfo.new_data)
    
    }]);
```

Comment: I dont see a return statement in `showInfo` function. That `return` is of map function.

Comment: Take a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681319/how-to-setup-service-to-pass-google-sheet-ids-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

**Service**

```
angular.module('myApp').service('chartService', function (){
    return {
        init: init,
        showInfo: showInfo
    };

    function init(path) {
        return Tabletop.init({
            key: path,
            callback: showInfo,
            simpleSheet: true 
        });
    }

    function showInfo(data, tabletop){
        return JSON.stringify(data.map(function(el) {
            return {
                "name": el[Object.keys(el)[0]],
                "y": +el[Object.keys(el)[1]]
            };
        }));
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('piechartCtrl', [ '$scope', 'chartService',  function (chartService, $scope) {
    var tabletop = chartService.init(),
        chartInfo = chartService.showInfo(someData, tabletop);

    console.log(chartInfo);        
}]);
```

I don't know exactly what you wanted with the parameters in showInfo but this should get you a good way in the right direction.

Comment: I just want then to show as they are in showinfo basically get the output from show info inside controller

Comment: @Imo well, if you read my code you'll probably understand how

Comment: This creates a new problem I was getting the Paths throw getUrl function resolve: {
        /* @ngInject */
        urls: function(chartService, config){
          if (config.path){
            return chartService.getUrls(config.path);
          }
        }
      }, and now I am unable to get the urls of spreadsheets

Answer (score 1):

Best way is with Promise.
In angular you have the q framework as $q service **[$q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)**

**Service**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('chartService', function($q) {
    var deferredSpreadsheet = $q.defer();
    return {
      getSpreadsheet: function init(path) {

        Tabletop.init({
          key: path,
          callback: showInfo,
          simpleSheet: true
        });
        return deferredSpreadsheet.promise;

      },

    }

    function showInfo(data, tabletop) {

      data = JSON.stringify(data.map(function(el) {
        return {
          "name": el[Object.keys(el)[0]],
          "y": el[Object.keys(el)[1]]
        };
      }));
      deferredSpreadsheet.resolve(data);

    }
  })
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('piechartCtrl', ['$scope', 'chartService', function($scope, chartService) {

    var path = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AmYzu_s7QHsmdDNZUzRlYldnWTZCLXdrMXlYQzVxSFE&output=html";
    var pro = chartService.getSpreadsheet(path).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)

    })


  }]);
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wsF03I6Fm7HwyoA9X49s?p=preview)

Answer (score -2):

Dirty way: You can use Broadcast and Emit

in the Service:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', JSONSTUFF);
```

in the Controller:

```
$scope.$on("myEvent", function(e, json){
console.log(json);
});
```